# Computing natural pseudo distance.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, normed-spaces, topological-data-analysis

Consider the functions $\varphi , \ \psi: \, D^2= \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2+y^2 \leq 1 \} \rightarrow \mathbb R $ defined by 
$$
\varphi (x,y):= \frac{5(1-x^2-y^2)}{2}
$$
and
$$
\psi (x,y):= 1 + \cos(3 \pi(x^2+y^2))
$$
for all $(x,y) \in D^2$. Compute the natural pseudodistance $d_G(\varphi, \psi)$ for $G=\text{Homeo}(D^2)$.

I've studied the problem in one dimension.

I found that $d_G(\varphi,\psi)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ studying persistence diagrams $D^1_\varphi$ and $D^1_\psi$ and computing the $d_{match}$. For this reason, I'd like to find out that $\frac{1}{2}$ is also an upper bound for $d_G$ in order to conclude that it is exactly $\frac{1}{2}$.

I tried to find a sequence $(g_n):[-1,1] \rightarrow [-1,1]$ of homeomorfisms such that
$$ \lim_n \ \lvert\lvert \varphi - \psi \circ g_n \lvert\lvert_\infty = \frac{1}{2} \ \ .$$

In doing so I consider $g_n(x)=x^n$, and now I have
$$\lim\limits_n \ \lvert\lvert \varphi - \psi \circ g_n \lvert\lvert_\infty \ \leq \ \limsup\limits_n \ \lvert\lvert \varphi - \psi \circ g_n \lvert\lvert_\infty = \ \lvert\lvert \varphi - \limsup\limits_n \ \psi \circ g_n \lvert\lvert_\infty  \ \ .$$
And
$$ \lvert\lvert \varphi - \limsup\limits_n \ \psi \circ g_n \lvert\lvert_\infty 
 \ = \lvert\lvert \frac{5}{2} (1-x^2) - \limsup\limits_n \ ( 1 +  \cos(3\pi x^{2n})) \lvert\lvert_\infty = \frac{1}{2} \ \ .$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Did you attempt to start solving the problem?

Comment: I found that $ d_G(\varphi,\psi) \geq \frac{1}{2}$ studying persistence diagrams $D_\varphi^1$ and $D_\psi^1$ and computing the $d_{match}$. For this reason, I'd like to find out that $\frac{1}{2}$ is also an upper bound for $d_G$ in order to conclude that it is exactly $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Could you please help me?